# Better solution for this loop and return data ? Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
convertType(arr) {
    let resultArr = arr.map(arr => {
      if (arr == '0') {
        return  'zero'
      }
      if (arr == '1') {
        return 'one'
      }
      if (arr == '2') {
        return   'two' 
      }
      if (arr == '3') {
        return  'three' 
      }
    })
    return resultArr;
  }
```

i need to find maybe a better solution for this loop and how to get these results back in a better way. Okay there is always a "switch" loop but what do you think about this? is it good?

This is work good , but i want better solution.

Comment: Not a good idea to shadow the `arr` variable inside your map.

Comment: "Better" by which terms? What keeps you from using a `switch`?

Answer (score 4):

I'd make an array and look up indicies:

```
const numbers = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
```

```
convertType(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => numbers[item]);
}
```

If the values being compared against aren't array indicies or might not have all values starting from 0, use an object:

```
const numbers = {
  2: 'two',
  3: 'three'
  somethingElse: 'something else'
};
```

with the same code for `convertType`.

Comment: very very nice. But can you explain me this numbers[item] ? Deep understanding ?

Comment: `obj[somePropName]` access the `somePropName` property of the `obj` object. The same thing applies to arrays. Eg, when `somePropName` is 0, `obj[somePropName]` is equivalent to `obj[0]`.The 0 property on the array contains the value `zero`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array.

```js
const arr = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
const data = ['0', '1', '3', '2', '2'];

const res = data.map(x => arr[Number(x)]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define possible cases in a global object as follows:

```js
const NUMBER_MAP = {
  '0': 'zero',
  '1': 'one',
  '2': 'two',
  '3': 'three',
};

function convertType(arr) {
  return arr.map(number => NUMBER_MAP[number] || 'not found');
}

console.log(convertType(['0','1','2','3','13']));
```